# Locust installation and run-up issues on Mac

Tags: python-3.x, performance-testing, locust, failed-installation

I am trying my hand at distributed load testing using Locust. My Mac Sonoma 14.0 is facing issues while installing Locust.

Details:

1. I already have Python 3.8.6 installed in my system
2. I tried installing Locust a year back, it was version 2.14, which ran stably, until it started running into issues, at which point I've uninstalled Locust from Pip and reinstalled it from same platform this time using the current stable version.

`pip3 install locust==2.18.0`

`pip show locust` response also doesn't seem to display all the required result as it should've. Is it because of an underlying package version conflict or could it be a different issue altogether?

[image]

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say exactly what is wrong, most probably it's a matter of your operating system paths.

In general it's recommended to use [virtual environments](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html) instead of installing packages globally and when you activate the virtual environment and install locust via pip it should be available

```
python3 -m venv locust && \
cd locust && \
source bin/activate && \
pip3 install -q locust && \
locust --version
```

[image]

There is also a [Homebrew formula](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/locust) so you should be able to get it as

```
brew install locust
```

More information: [What Is Locust Load Testing?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/locust-load-testing)

Comment: hi, Thanks for prompt reply. I had installed it within the virtual environment itself. PFA screenshot: https://medium.com/@puja.bhattacharya.pb/troubleshooting-locust-issues-9f3f7250c440  and was still getting the error

Comment: Locust doesnt have additional/any paths to be setup post installation so far till its 2.18 release, and highly doubt that MIT would introduce this change going forward

Answer (score -1):

Upon further investigation, these are my findings. This would help someone who is trying to setup locust in similar system config as mine(mentioned in above question).

There seems to be an issue with Sonoma version and Locust stable version whose underlying packages.
A partial solution is right now to do the installation via **home brew** currently till a solution to the pip bug is pushed in managing the underlying conflict and dependency right now..

Installation in python environment really doesn't give any solution, as the issue is in pip not having supported dependency packages for Sonoma os.

**Restriction:** With this solution, locust can only be run in headless mode for now. The port 8089, from my system has nothing running on it, still doesn't support the command to open the flask interface which comes as a default package with locust, when trying to reach localhost:8089

If someone is interested in knowing this current open bug and troubleshooting struggles, you can refer it [here](https://medium.com/@puja.bhattacharya.pb/troubleshooting-locust-issues-9f3f7250c440) on my blog.

It additionally has the link to the github issue too.